# Assert failure with same expected and actual value

Tags: json, munit

Encountered munit failure with similar actual value  and expected value. Both expected and actual value is in json format.
But the only different is their byte array. The actual value has 419 bytes and the expected value has 600 bytes.                                             Could you help us how to solve this. Thanks

```
java.lang.AssertionError: The response payload is not correct! expected:<[
  {
    "type": "abc",
    "customerAccount": "111",
    "id": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "type": "abc",
    "customerAccount": "111",
    "id": "ABC"
  }
]> but was:<[
  {
    "type": "abc",
    "customerAccount": "111",
    "id": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "type": "abc",
    "customerAccount": "111",
    "id": "ABC"
  }
]>
    at post:/products/search:application/json:api-config-200-application/json-FlowTest.munit:assert-on-equals{doc:name=assert that - payload is as expected, actualValue=[
  {
    "type": "abc",
    "customerAccount": "111",
    "id": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "type": "abc",
    "customerAccount": "111",
    "id": "ABC"
  }
], expectedValue=[
  {
    "type": "abc",
    "customerAccount": "111",
    "id": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "type": "abc",
    "customerAccount": "111",
    "id": "ABC"
  }
], message=The response payload is not correct!}(api-apikit-test.xml:31)
```

Comment: If you are expecting json to be same, why not to compare jsons?

Comment: Yes, I compare the json but it failed.                                                       
The flow's last component is DataWeave, and the output payload has mime type application/json. 
                                
 https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/54465/munit-java-convert-object-to-json.html

Comment: Could you please show us the code of the test, the assertion part in particular.

Comment: It works. I just used jackson object mapper readTree()...                           #[(new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper().readTree(payload.toString())).equals(new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper().readTree(getResource('scaffolder/response/post_200_cust_search_app_json.json').asString()))]